# How to implement cubic spline interpolation in 3 dimensions?

Tags: python, interpolation, spline, cubic

I am trying to implement cubic spline interpolation in 3 dimensions, however I am unsure how to modify the code I have currently written to implement the z-axis. The purpose of this code will be to calculate a trajectory between a starting point and an end point, which passes through several intermediate points. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.array([1, 5, 8, 12, 16, 20, 25, 30, 38], np.float)
Y = np.array([20, 14, 10, 7, 3, 8, 17, 5, 3], np.float)

num_points = 1000

H_x = np.diff(X)
H_y = np.diff(Y)
H_n = N - 1

Alfa = 1 / H_x[1 : H_n - 1]
Gamma = 1 / H_x[1 : H_n - 1]
Beta = 2 * (1 / H_x[:H_n - 1] + 1 / H_x[1:])

dF = H_y / H_x
Delta = 3 * (dF[1:] / H_x[1:] + dF[:H_n-1] / H_x[:H_n-1])

TDM = np.diag(Alfa, k=-1) + np.diag(Beta, 0) + np.diag(Gamma, +1)
B = np.linalg.solve(TDM, Delta)
B = np.hstack([0, B, 0])

C = (3*dF - B[1:] - 2 * B[:H_n]) / H_x
D = (B[:H_n] + B[1:] - 2 * dF) / (H_x ** 2)

x_step = (X[N-1] - X[0]) / num_points

x_points = []
x_base = X[0]
for i in range(num_points):
    x_points.append(x_base+x_step*i)

y_points = []
for x_point in x_points:
    for i in range(N-1):
        if ((x_point >= X[i]) and (x_point <= X[i+1])):
            y_point = Y[i] + B[i] * (x_point - X[i]) + C[i] * ((x_point - X[i]) ** 2) + D[i] * ((x_point - X[i]) ** 3)
            y_points.append(y_point)

spline, nodes = plt.plot(x_points, y_points, "-g", X, Y, "o")

plt.axis([X[0]-3, X[N-1]+3, np.min(y_points)-3, np.max(y_points)+3])
plt.title(u'P(x)')
plt.xlabel(u'X')
plt.ylabel(u'Y')
plt.grid()
plt.savefig('cubic_spline.png', format = 'png')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions. What kind of modification are you trying to do? what is the output you are getting and would like to get?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with plotting. Please provide a [mcve].